# cursor.execute() not uploading rows to sqlite database

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, database-cursor

I built a scraper that saves to a .csv file and am now attempting to save rows from that .csv file to an sqlite3 database with an IF statement, but it's not working. I've tried formatting the values in a dozen different ways and am getting nowhere.

"Match" prints every time the IF statement is True, but the row doesn't get added to the sqlite database. Calling cur.fetchall()/one()/etc results in 'None' being returned.

```
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jobs_table")
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
                                   jobs_table(id TEXT,
                                              date TEXT,
                                              company TEXT, 
                                              position TEXT,
                                              tags TEXT,
                                              description TEXT,
                                              url TEXT)''')

skills = ('python')
for row in csv_data:
    if skills in row.get('description').lower():
        print('')
        print('Match!')
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO jobs_table(id,  
                                            date,  
                                            company,  
                                            position,  
                                            tags,  
                                            description,  
                                            url) VALUES(:id,   
                                                        :epoch,   
                                                        :date,   
                                                        :company,   
                                                        :position,   
                                                        :tags,   
                                                        :description,   
                                                        :url)", row)
```

I assume the problem is in my cur.execute() function, but I can't figure out how else it should be run. Any takers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling `cur.fetchone()` right after the `cur.execute()` is normal to get `None` (or `[]` for `cur.fetchall()`). You need to execute a query first to get the results, for example `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM jobs_table")`.

Comment: Thanks! One of those cases of being too close to it for too long!